# Upsert - Update if exists else Insert in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I'm looking for a simple upsert (Update/Insert). The tables looks like this

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)     | YES  | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

There is no key here. The idea is to insert if email is different, else update. The [Insert on duplicate key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in mysql  doesn't suit the purpose.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: So `id` is a non-unique field? Multiple persons can have the same id?

Comment: Upsert doesn't make sense without a unique key. How do you determine if a row exists? If it matches on all fields does it already exists or does it only have to match on one or two fields?

Comment: yeah id is the primary key, updated the schema

Comment: Now that you have a unique key you can use the "on duplicate key update" syntax, correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot add a unique key on the email column, you'll check to see if the record exists first (preferably in a transaction):

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE email = 'my@example.com' FOR UPDATE
```

then update the record if it exists:

```
UPDATE mytable SET name = 'my name' WHERE id = ?
```

otherwise insert it:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name, email) VALUES ('my name', 'my@example.com')
```

Comment: is there a way to do this in a single sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
REPLACE INTO table VALUES(1,'hello', 'world@example.com');
```